# Python: Nested Dictionary duplicate values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am not that experienced in python so it might be the case that I am missing something which is already there.. But it would be great if anyone can help me sort this out.
I have a nested dictionary which is something of the following form:
Main dictionary has key: userid
then in this the particular user has rated (maybe) 20 different products
So the nested dictionary has a key: product id
and value is the rating
I am reading these from a file: where the first word is user id, second word is movie id: and the third word is rating

```
dataDict={}
innerDict = {}
for line in myFile:
        words = line.strip().split()
        userId = words[0]
        movieId = words[1]
        rating = words[2]
        innerDict[movieId] = rating
        dataDict[userId] = (innerDict)
        innerDict = {}
```

But clearly the line
     innerDict[userId] = innerDict will create a new (instead of appending it to the last one..)
The way I have written API, I have to work with these datastructures only.. (no appending to the list) it has to be a nested dictionary only..
Thanks

Comment: You're deleting `innerDict` right after creating it. `dataDict[userId]` will then contain an empty dict...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to add a new inner dict to the outer dict only if it doesn't exist yet, right? Then you need to use [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
dataDict={}
for line in myFile:
        words = line.strip().split()
        userId = words[0]
        movieId = words[1]
        rating = words[2]
        innerDict = dataDict.setdefault(userId, {})
        innerDict[movieId] = rating
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is

```
datadict = {"user1": {"Gladiator": 9, "Ghost": 2, "Jurassic Park": 8},
            "user2": {"E.T.": 0, "300": 10}
           }
```

Right?

Then you just need [`setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
datadict.setdefault(userId, {})[movieId] = rating
```

`setdefault` creates a new empty dict if the key doesn't yet exist, otherwise returns the dict you've already got.